# How do I make my fluid thinner?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am using the fluid sim in Blender 3.1.2 and it works great except my fluid is thick. How do I make it thinner?

When I attempt to reduce the thickness of my cube (that has fluid) the fluid sim stops baking anything. It only bakes if the cube is thick enough.

What it looks like at frame 0:

[image]

At frame 10:

[image]

Ideally I want something like this dripping water on a cube:

[image]

My fluid cube settings:

[image]

My domain settings:

[image]

Comment: Well, first of all the viscosity is way too high from my experience... way too high. And of course it stops baking if you make the cube too thin if the resolution in the domain is so low that a voxel won't fit inside the cube anymore... The dripping water on the cube is hard to achieve I guess, since in reality water molecules are coming together by cohesion until the resulting drop is so large that its weight pulled by gravity overcomes the adhesion, spoken amateurishly. Don't think Mantaflow is simulating realistically enough, and presumably you don't have a real world scale on your sim?

Comment: You're right about viscosity - I think I was just testing and I am currently using `0.0005` which is much better. I got way better results by splitting my cube into smaller cubes (still with the same thickness). Might post it as my answer. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: You're welcome. Some time ago I was experimenting with viscosity, too... but I got a little frustrated because it was either much too thick or it somehow messed up the simulation so that I gave up - hence I'm not giving an answer to this. So you're good to go ;)